# Html Input button to perform print from inside a gridview

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, input, printing

I have the following code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewProducts_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="GridViewProducts_Bound" CssClass="gridviewproducts"
  DataKeyNames="ID">

   <asp:BoundField DataField="id" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="nAME" />
   <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <input type="button" id="btnPrint" value="Print" runat="server" onserverclick="Button_ShowDetails_Click" />
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

and my javascript :

```
$(function () {
 $("#btnPrint").click(function () {
     var contents = $("#dvContents").html();
     var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
     frame1[0].name = "frame1";
     frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
     $("body").append(frame1);
     var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
     frameDoc.document.open();
     //Create a new HTML document.
     frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>Bestilling</title>');
     frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
     //Append the external CSS file.
     frameDoc.document.write('<link href="Content/Site2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
     //Append the DIV contents.
     frameDoc.document.write(contents);
     frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
     frameDoc.document.close();
     setTimeout(function () {
         window.frames["frame1"].focus();
         window.frames["frame1"].print();
         frame1.remove();
     }, 500);
 });
```

});

And the html:

```
<div> ... some info to be printed ... </div>
```

This works if the button is outside the gridview, but now since it's performing some server side action, it's not working. I'm not getting any error messages either, it's simply just doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the generated HTML. You will see that the ID of button `btnPrint` has been renamed to something like `GridViewProducts_btnPrint_0` because there are more that one in a GridView (or Repeater etc).

Better bind on a class name in the GridView, so give your buttons a class name.

```
<input type="button" id="btnPrint" class="PrintButton" value="Print" runat="server" />
```

And then bind the click to all the buttons with that class inside the GridView.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%= GridViewProducts.ClientID %> .PrintButton").click(function () {
        //do your stuff
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi
Sorry for the late respone, I will look into your solution later :-)